# How to make an .fbx file's Avatar into a separate prefab?

Tags: unity, animation

Editor version: Unity 2021.3.21f

I've got a default Mixamo Y-bot .fbx, which was changed to allow for specific animations.

In the Unity Editor, I created/defined an Avatar from the model. I need to use this Avatar in a prefab of a similar character.
[image: Avatar definition settings for the .fbx]

How do I split the Avatar from the .fbx, so that I may use it as a standalone prefab and add it to the similar character's prefab?

[image: .fbx in the editor; Avatar circled]

If I simply CTRL+D thigs, the asset is duplicated but I'm unable to use it. Unity says it can't find it (see error below) if I add the duplicate asset as the Avatar in the prefab's animator.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

UnityEditor.ModelImporterRigEditor.CopyHumanDescriptionToDestination (UnityEditor.SerializedObject sourceObject, UnityEditor.SerializedObject targetObject) (at <57a8ad0d1492436d8cfee9ba8e6618f8>:0)

UnityEditor.ModelImporterRigEditor.CopyHumanDescriptionFromOtherModel (UnityEngine.Avatar sourceAvatar) (at <57a8ad0d1492436d8cfee9ba8e6618f8>:0)

UnityEditor.ModelImporterRigEditor.CopyAvatarGUI () (at <57a8ad0d1492436d8cfee9ba8e6618f8>:0)

UnityEditor.ModelImporterRigEditor.HumanoidGUI () (at <57a8ad0d1492436d8cfee9ba8e6618f8>:0)

UnityEditor.ModelImporterRigEditor.OnInspectorGUI () (at <57a8ad0d1492436d8cfee9ba8e6618f8>:0)

UnityEditor.AssetImporterTabbedEditor.OnInspectorGUI () (at <57a8ad0d1492436d8cfee9ba8e6618f8>:0)

UnityEditor.ModelImporterEditor.OnInspectorGUI () (at <57a8ad0d1492436d8cfee9ba8e6618f8>:0)

UnityEditor.UIElements.InspectorElement+<>c__DisplayClass59_0.<CreateIMGUIInspectorFromEditor>b__0 () (at <cd89fd1ce037419f95985196f5aeee4d>:0)

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```